# Redux Persist using Redux Toolkit in React

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I wanna store states after refreshing the page, so I used Redux Persist and followed the instructions at [LogRocket](https://blog.logrocket.com/persist-state-redux-persist-redux-toolkit-react/), I failed again and again because my configureStore is different. Can you please tell me how to do it?

Here is my store.js

```js
// store.js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import appSlice from './appSlice';
  
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        app: appSlice.reducer,
    }
});

export default store
```

Here is my index.js

```js
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { App } from './App';
import store from './data/store';
import './index.css'
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

// const store = configureStore({ reducer: App });
// const store = createStore(Reducer)
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/*" element={<App/>} />
        </Routes>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Thank you in advance!

When I follow the instructions, console shows couldn't find app store

Comment: What if you just followed the [official documentation](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) instead of some random blog?

Answer (score 0):

```
   // create store.js like this

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'; // defaults to localStorage for web

// add the reducers that need to be persisted
const reducersToPersist = [];

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  whitelist: reducersToPersist
};

const reducers = combineReducers({
// Your reducers
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
});

const persistor = persistStore(store);

export { store, persistor };
```

in your root file

```
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { persistor, store } from './store';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
       <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          {/* Your Project routes */}
       </PersistGate>
     </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```